# UnableToResolveError : unable to resolve module `merge` from Libraries/ART/React Native ART.js

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-android

I am new to React-native.

I am stuck with this error : 
UnableToResolveError : unable to resolve module `merge` from Libraries/ART/ReactNativeART.js

dependencies I have used are :

```
"dependencies": {
    "apsl-react-native-button": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.2",
    "react-native-deprecated-custom-components": "^0.1.0",
    .....................
  },
```

in node_modules -> react-native/Libraries/ART/ReactNativeART.js file is also available.

When I run `react-native run-android` command, I am facing this error.

Can anyone help me in this ?

Comment: even i got this error when i created a new react-native project.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to install this module `npm i --save merge`